# Datetime format (python) to cvs

Tags: python, datetime

Anyone know, why it doesn't save the dates in datetime format (Python) to csv?
I converted my dates (str) to datetime:

```
Fecha=pd.to_datetime(df1oct['fecha_hora'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df1oct['Fecha']=Fecha
df1oct = df1oct[['Fecha', 'P1', 'P2', 'Calidad']]
df1oct['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1oct['Fecha'])
df1oct= df1oct.set_index('datetime')
df1oct.drop(['Fecha'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

and I saved the final df:

```
resulto.to_csv('resulto5.csv', index=False)
```

But it only saves the information without the dates

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To save the date I must Reset the index:

```
resulto.reset_index()
```